# Как получить все ключи массива $request в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить все ключи массива $request в Laravel? Подскажите способ без перебора этого массива, без всяких циклов. Должен же быть простой метод из коробки.

Comment: Да откройте уже мануал хоть раз - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: `array_keys($request->all());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если из коробки, то можно так:

```
$keys = request()->request->keys();
```

Comment: Круто работает, но непонятно что это за свойство ->request и метод keys не нашел в документации